# Writing a Password Filter for Windows in C# and registering the dll

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, passwords

I'm looking to write a custom [password filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms721882(VS.85).aspx) for windows using C#.Net. Any inputs on that? I have already read the [programming considerations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms721884(v=VS.85).aspx) for writing a password filter. I'm not able to find any code sample in C#.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okie, I found that it cannot be (should not be) done.

"The behavior of any high-level language, framework, or runtime in the components that are loaded by core operating system processes is undefined."

http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;841927

Answer (score 0):

2 short rep to simply comment...

The link is dead, but a brief search on the web indicates it was originally titled:

> 841927 Do not use high level languages, libraries, frameworks, virtual
>   machines or runtimes in core operating system processes

Also, I cannot find any reference to this KB article on the MS site any more. I somehow doubt this guidance would have changed but that is how it is today, 9 years later.